# Java -classpath directory traversal

Tags: java

**Given the following directory structure:**

x-|

```
     |- GoDeep.class | 
     |- test-|  
             |- MyJar.jar |
             |- myApp-|
                      |-Foo.java
                      |-Foo.class
```

And given the contents of GoDeep.java and Foo.java:

```
3. public class GoDeep {
4. public static void main(String[] args) {
5. System.out.println(myApp.Foo.d);
6. }
7. }

3. package myApp;
4. public class Foo { public static int d = 8; }
```

And MyJar.jar contains the following entry:

myApp/Foo.class

If the current directory is x, which commands will successfully execute GoDeep.class and
produce the output 8? (Choose all that apply.)

A. java GoDeep

B. java -classpath . GoDeep

C. java -classpath test/MyJar.jar GoDeep

D. java GoDeep -classpath test/MyJar.jar

E. java GoDeep -classpath test/MyJar.jar:.

F. java -classpath .:test/MyJar.jar GoDeep

G. java -classpath test/MyJar.jar:. GoDeep

I think answer should be B) F) and G). However, book says F) and G). I know that when we use "java" , both files (GoDeep and Foo) must be checked in classpath set as a default (i.e  x). whereas in case of "javac" it will only search a file which is needed (Foo) to execute our original file(GoDeep) ; the original file is not been searched in classpath. if i am wrong please correct me.

In option B) we used "java -classpath . GoDeep" and our current directory is x. Then using (.) it will check in current directory. In this case both files are available in x directory then why its not correct option?

Thanks in advance. Question is from SCJP6

Comment: Using `.` will not look inside any jars.

Comment: What package have you put GoDeep in?

Comment: is in only the case in jars? i mean if its not jar , then it can look?

Comment: Yes. However, it also won't search sub-directories, so that's why it doesn't add Foo.class either.

Comment: so what files it can include if (.) is used? it can look test,myapp?

Comment: why it doesnt include Foo.class? because its sub-directory? Is it always like this? please reply